# video card architecture

Tags: architecture, hardware, visualization

Can anyone point me to some information on what a modern video card architecture looks like? I'm particularly interested in understanding how my rendering engine will be executed by the GPU.

Ideally, I'd get two answers: one related to today's monster video cards and one related to today's mobile GPU's.

-- edit follows

Thanks for the input so far. Considering the proprietary and changing nature of video card hardware, it seems there's not the ideal answer that I was looking for. So I'll clarify and ask a couple very specific questions. (I guess I was hoping to get a resource similar to http://www.realityprime.com/articles/scenegraphs-past-present-and-future which would generally provide me with lots of information on hardware that might be relevant to me.)

First off, I'm quite familiar with the OpenGL pipeline. A google-images search for my question title, "video card architecture," reveals diagrams of various video cards which naturally seem to match the graphics pipeline. While this makes sense, and is helpful, it leaves out some details. I'll try to get at a couple specifics.

1) What happens when a texture change (glBindTexture(), or new sampler specified) is issued? Obviously, the command is queued and later processed by the video card, but is the texture loaded immediately into cache, or not until something attempts to sample that texture? I would expect the latter, partly because the texture may not entirely fit into such caches to begin with. How big are these caches, anyway?

2) Older video cards had hardware dedicated specifically for a given type of shader. Newer video cards reuse the same hardware for all types of shaders. Are these "stream processors" typically shared with other computations throughout the pipeline, such as culling?

3) It seems that progress related to video card hardware has largely been lead by innovation in software. Are there any interesting cases where the opposite is true? I still hope that there might be some resource that gives a detailed history of video card design, similar to the scenegraphs article linked above.

4) Mobile GPU was an ambiguous term. I'm hoping that eBusiness assumed I meant mobile as in laptop when he called me ignorant -- I was rather referring to the GPUs embedded in modern cell phones and tablets.

Comment: We surely have some nice answer, but there is kinda neat descripion of rendering pipeline on the gaming.se http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/22286/what-is-a-pixel-shader

Comment: Added a bounty... if I get a really good answer I'll donate 50 of my precious reputation points!

Comment: @Notabene Are you trying to tell me that you can't get a mobile graphics chip with anything newer than shader model 2? Or did I read your comment wrong?

Comment: @stephelton This question ask a way too broad question, if you really get what you ask for it will be too much information to sort through, so if you hope to get an at least somewhat useful answer I suggest you answer my question, why do you ask? What problem do you hope to solve? What improvement in your programming would you achieve? I may be harsh, but you didn't ask a good question, and a bounty doesn't solve that, it just attracts shotgun answers.

Comment: @eBusiness yes, i thought that mobile GPU means gpu in cell phones. I'm not into that, so i don't know current state. So i'm probably wrong

Comment: @stephelton Sorry, I thought you meant laptop GPUs. Though I still think you'll have a hard time finding fundamental logical differences between phone and desktop/laptop GPUs beyond the general noise of variations between implementations, it's not a stupid question.

Comment: Remember, if you feel a comment or answer is inappropriate in any way, you can quietly flag it.

Comment: @rlb.usa wouldn't you say the same thing about an original post?

Comment: @eBusiness That's kind of what I'm getting at -- are there any real differences other than scale?

Comment: I don't know all the details, I just saw a question that needed some attention. But basically, stuff like skipping a dedicated circuit and offloading it's functionality to shaders is exactly the kind of stuff that may be different from chip to chip, that is why we have DX and OGL, so that you don't have to worry about it. There is a lot to learn about this kind of stuff, but little to use that knowledge for as a software developer, since you are practically forced to use an abstraction anyway. For cell phone GPUs you'll find differences in features, and that is important.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not all GPU architecture is that hidden, it really depends on the company.

[Imagination](http://www.imgtec.com/powervr/VGX150.asp) for example :)

Many mobile devices use the [PowerVR SGX](http://www.imgtec.com/images/blockdiagrams/powervr/large/POWERVR_SGX_lrg.gif), which you can see has a USSE where multiple shader processing units are added as necessary. These take care of your shaders, the culling, etc is generally done elsewhere.

These GPU's often use [Tile Based Rendering](http://developer.amd.com/gpu_assets/gdc2008_ribble_maurice_TileBasedGpus.pdf) as it can allow optimizations especially in shader time.

There is also a tendancy to make blending part of the programmable pipeline, where either you reprogram a specific blending chip, or the blending is included in the shaders, see the [VR Core](http://www.imgtec.com/images/blockdiagrams/powervr/large/POWERVR_VGX150_lrg.gif).

You can get lots of info about their specific GPU, its definately a good start.

I also found [this article](http://techreport.com/articles.x/8342/1) about the XBox360 chip layout.

And for your other questions :
1) I don't think it would be easy to see how the data is cached, I would guess the mentality is more 'load things into cache and keep what we think will be needed later', generally caches are small though, because it's very fast, expensive memory.

2) As stated, you generally have many different things going on outside of the shaders (see [this](http://goanna.cs.rmit.edu.au/~gl/teaching/Interactive3D/2011/lecture2.html)). An easy example is the Rasterization & Interpolation getting your from Vertex positions, to thousand of fragments with an interpolated color, which is done on the GPU.

3) Shaders came from Pixar :)

4) I didn't think it was ambiguous, what is also interesting are the Intel HD chips that are directly integrated into the Core ix's.

Comment: Actually Ken Perlin was the one who invented shaders (as he claims) :)

Comment: Ken Perlin does make a lot of noise!
(Ahaha chortle chortle...)

Answer (score 1):

A lot of architecture information hare hidden behind NDA:s so it might be hard to give a good answer accurate to the current state. You might want to read [this](http://http.developer.nvidia.com/GPUGems2/gpugems2_chapter30.html) nvidia article that describes how the GeForce 6 works.

Of course a lot has changed since, vertex/fragment units have been unified and can be load balanced, but the overall architecture (that you need to know about for writing general apps) is pretty much the same. More shading stages has been added, and a few more fixed function steps (tesselator etc.) These works very much the same way as the steps in the nvidia article, except that they pull computation resources from a pool of units.

As said by seanmiddleditch in his answer, AMD has released a lot of specifications of their chips. You can find them [here](http://www.x.org/docs/AMD/). Especially the [Radeon R6xx/R7xx Acceleration](http://www.x.org/docs/AMD/R6xx_R7xx_3D.pdf) PDF should be of interest to you.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not aware of any hardware-level design documentation, but there's plenty of information publicly available on hardware interfaces and behaviors that might help you out.

AMD has programming information for their GPUs available on their developer portal, which in turn explains how the hardware works in a high level way.

The Direct3D documentation from Microsoft also fairly clearly explains at a high level how the 3D pipeline used by basically all GPUs works.

Finally, you can also look at Mesa3D, which is a complete Open Source implementation of software OpenGL, which basically means an "emulator" for a generic modern GPU.  (Plus Mesa includes hardware drivers for many modern GPUs, including most AMD and some NVIDIA GPUs, which you could also study if the public documentation isn't enough for you.)

Comment: Good thought on consulting the mesa source code. It's available here: http://webcvs.freedesktop.org/mesa/Mesa/

Comment: While mesa might be a good read to learn how the rendering pipeline can be implemented, it might not be the best way to learn about how the hardware actually works. A good 3D pipeline primer like "Computer Graphics with OpenGL (Hearn&Baker)" will probably give you the same with better explanation.

Answer (score 1):

OK, [this](http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/2_0/docs/NVIDIA_CUDA_Programming_Guide_2.0.pdf) is the full blown programmers manual (and I think a dated one) for CUDA which gives a lot of details on the nvidia architecture. It seems overwhelming but if you just start going through it I think you will find that the diagrams along with the explanations of them can be very helpful.

Comment: Whether its evil or no I make no claim about, but the question was about hardware architecture and the programming guide gives a lot of information about that.

Comment: I agree, I was being stupid. I programmed with CUDA back in the early days (when we could start using it with C) and it was a nightmare to use. Hence the good memories.

Answer (score 1):

> 1) What happens when a texture change
>   (glBindTexture(), or new sampler
>   specified) is issued? Obviously, the
>   command is queued and later processed
>   by the video card, but is the texture
>   loaded immediately into cache, or not
>   until something attempts to sample
>   that texture? I would expect the
>   latter, partly because the texture may
>   not entirely fit into such caches to
>   begin with. How big are these caches,
>   anyway?

I'm not sure of the size of the caches. However, everything pretty much is load-on-demand for the GPU- after all, what happens if I want to use that cache due to a queued command between now and when the that particular texture change is queued?

> 2) Older video cards had hardware
>   dedicated specifically for a given
>   type of shader. Newer video cards
>   reuse the same hardware for all types
>   of shaders. Are these "stream
>   processors" typically shared with
>   other computations throughout the
>   pipeline, such as culling?

As far as I know, every operation which is not explicitly shadable is implemented in hardware. This is faster, but also, the shaders in modern games can dominate the performance very strongly- you're mostly shader-limited.

> 3) It seems that progress related to
>   video card hardware has largely been
>   lead by innovation in software. Are
>   there any interesting cases where the
>   opposite is true? I still hope that
>   there might be some resource that
>   gives a detailed history of video card
>   design, similar to the scenegraphs
>   article linked above.

Pretty much no. This is because every technique can be implemented in software before it can be implemented in hardware- and indeed, software implementation first would be necessary to learn about relative performance, what data it depends on, and things like that, and the output of compiling programs can be used to determine what kind of hardware is needed, gauging developer demand, that kind of thing. That's ignoring all the time it would take to implement in hardware, of course.

One case that I *can* name, effectively, is concurrency in CPU design, where the necessity of moving to multiple cores in hardware has spawned massive concurrency efforts in software. Of course, software threads existed before, but concurrency was nothing like as it is now.

> 4) Mobile GPU was an ambiguous term.
>   I'm hoping that eBusiness assumed I
>   meant mobile as in laptop when he
>   called me ignorant -- I was rather
>   referring to the GPUs embedded in
>   modern cell phones and tablets.

They're basically just desktop GPUs, but downscaled. This is because desktop GPUs are still very optimized pieces of hardware performing a dedicated function, giving them much implementation experience and optimization, and developer existing knowledge. If you have a mobile GPU that works completely differently, then nobody is gonna figure out how to use it, it's gonna be much slower (relatively to how it would be), etc. Of course, some systems require changing to be mobile-feasible, but in the general case, it's the best idea to downscale what's available for desktop. This is not quite the same for CPUs, as mobile CPUs have also been around for a long time.

Comment: "They're basically just desktop GPUs, but downscaled" - I disagree with this.
Not only do they often have different architecture, but often don't even supply commands that are anything like typical OpenGL or DirectX.

Answer (score 0):

> 1) What happens when a texture change
>   is issued?

Most chips simply change where the texture sampler requests memory from. I know of no chip that preloads textures in caches, simply because textures tend to be way bigger than the caches, and with multiple textures, it makes even less sense. Moreover, most PC chips have multiple texture samplers, with dedicated caches. And you certainly don't want to load all the caches with the same data.

To give you an idea, with a back-of-the envelope math: preloading would mean transferring all the texture memory of all the active textures each frame (something along the line of 300MB for a mid-range title, 1GB+ for high-end titles). Whereas just loading the parts of the texture that are effectively used brings that down to about ~30MB-100MB / frame (very broad strokes, thinking 1-2 megapixel, with an average of 30B-50B/pixel texture data). The cost of preloading is higher than not by up to an order of magnitude, ignoring the issue of whether it can fit.

The main issue with not preloading is hiding the latency of the memory fetches. GPUs are built to hide this latency (by typically running many threads at the same time on a single processor)

> 2) Are these "stream processors"
>   typically shared with other
>   computations throughout the pipeline,
>   such as culling?

It depends on the hardware. Some chips are known to do [clipping on the processors](http://intellinuxgraphics.org/Vol_2_G45_3dmedia.pdf), e.g. (though culling is easy enough to do in pure h/w). Many mobile chips do the blending et al. alongside the fragment shader, as opposed to dedicate hardware for it. There's even an nvidia extension to do that yourself in the shader as opposed to use the fixed function state: [nv_shader_framebuffer_fetch](http://developer.download.nvidia.com/tegra/docs/tegra_gles2_development.pdf).

> 3) It seems that progress related to
>   video card hardware has largely been
>   lead by innovation in software. Are
>   there any interesting cases where the
>   opposite is true?

I'm not sure what you're after with this question. Hardware vendors do not add features on a whim. They do so because they see value in them being used by software (even if it's not today's software). Can you be more specific maybe ?

> 4) I was rather referring to the GPUs
>   embedded in modern cell phones and
>   tablets.

GPUs in cellphones today are mostly Imagination or Tegra. Those 2 architectures already have very different structures. The Imagination ones (SGX parts) are fairly well documented on their websites (and use a tiled-base architecture. See 3nixios good answer on this). Tegra less so. All I could find was that [Tegra 2 is not unified](http://www.anandtech.com/show/4144/lg-optimus-2x-nvidia-tegra-2-review-the-first-dual-core-smartphone/5), pointing to a hardware base that is ~DX9.